# How do I make a web Request in c?

Tags: get, httprequest

I have build a MySQL database and an interface using php, that returns json documents. I now want to know how I can do a web request (GET parameters) to get that json document. Most solutions I have found include  or something like that, and i dont have these libraries (working on win 10 x64).

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Step #1 find suitable libraries.

Comment: I didn't find such, that's why I'm asking :/